# Mysql Cluster create table - errno:157

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I am trying to setup a mysql cluster and I have started ndb_mgmd first and then ndbd on the data nodes followed by mysqld. I get the following at `ndb_mgm -e show` on the management node.

```
Cluster Configuration
---------------------

[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s)
id=2    @10.252.151.67  (Version: 5.1.68, Nodegroup: 0, Master)
id=3    @10.253.4.143  (Version: 5.1.68, Nodegroup: 0)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1    @10.253.19.149  (Version: 5.1.68)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4    @10.253.4.143  (Version: 5.1.68)
id=5    @10.252.151.67  (Version: 5.1.68)
```

when I try to create a database on one of the datanodes, I get the following error

```
create table user_table(
  ycsb_key varchar(32) primary key,
  field1 varchar(100), field2 varchar(100), field3 varchar(100), field4 varchar(100),
  field5 varchar(100), field6 varchar(100), field7 varchar(100), field8 varchar(100),
  field9 varchar(100), field10 varchar(100))
  max_rows=1000 engine=ndbcluster partition by key(ycsb_key);
```

I get this  error:

`ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'user_database.user_table' (errno: 157)`

Did anyone get similar error?

Answer (score 0):

Start the cluster (start your ndbd processes and bring them online) and then restart the cluster, it seems to help, take a look at this [thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?25,133034,133034)

Comment: I am following the exact same process but it still throws the error, I am using an old version of mysql cluster(5.1.68), do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: @hld619 i can not tell for sure, but i do on tthink so, there are alot of people facing this with MSQL, i suggest you write to the MySQL Support since there are too much potential causes for this. http://forums.mysql.com/index.php

Comment: I was able to setup the mysql cluster with the latest version (7.2.12). I think it may be a bug in the older version.

Comment: Good for you, i checked an older version where such a problem was reported and the support saied its not a bug in that version, maby it came on later versions.